# Alto saxophone learner

Tags: technique

Any tips on how to go from C flat to D flat quickly on alto saxophone? (Besides practice.) It's difficult. I kind of put off learning the low C flat key. I'm going through Larry Teal's book and I'm discouraged on D flat major. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First question: what model sax do you have, and do the low-end keys have a full set of hinges and rollers to facilitate slide-fingerings? Have you verified with a teacher or repair shop that everything is in perfect working order?

The lowest notes on a sax can be the most difficult to get to "sound" (start up cleanly) until you've practiced and built up breath control.  That may be part of the problem.

Are you trying to slur or articulate? Each has its own "tricks" to improve the transition.  In the end, you should do two things:
1) Have a qualified teacher work with you on finger motion and coordination with breath and tonguing.
2) Practice, practice, practice.

Comment: Thanks. I started practicing. I was tired yesterday when I asked the question.